# Can I run two read queries on different tables in parallel in a transaction when using postgres?

Tags: database, postgresql, typeorm

I'm using postgres with typeorm. I want to fetch data from 2 tables in parallel. Although typeorm does allow me to do that, does it mean that both the queries are run in parallel?

Here's a simplified version of what I'm trying to do:

```
const [result1, result2] = await Promise.allSettled([
   transactionEntityManager.findBy(Entity1, ...),
   transactionEntityManager.findBy(Entity2, ...)
]);
```

I've checked [this](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1014#issuecomment-336397434) issue and I know that I cannot use `Promise.all()`. But, my question here is if we can have parallel queries inside a transaction, and if it improves performance?

Answer (score 2):

The only way to run two SQL statements in parallel is to use two database connections. If you do that, there should be no problem. But depending on what you want to do, there may be additional considerations:

- If both queries should see the same state of the database, one of the transactions should export its snapshot via `pg_export_snapshot()` and the other should use [`SET TRANSACTION SNAPSHOT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set-transaction.html) to import it.
- If you want to modify data that way, you need a *distributed transaction* that uses the two-phase commit protocol. See [`PREPARE TRANSACTION`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-prepare-transaction.html) for details. Heed the warning on that page: if you don't use a reliable *transaction manager*, this approach will cause major trouble.